# Best way to download images and use them in an Android ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I'm new to Android development and currently trying things out, but I'm not yet experienced enough to tell which way to do things is the best.

I'm trying to populate a custom ListView containing items with an ImageView and a TextView (like a list of cars for example) from a web API or something, but I'm unsure which is the best way to deal with images. What I'm concerned about is a possible large scale list containing hundreds of cars with an image each. Obviously we don't want to store all of these images on the device, however Won't downloading all of these images create a memory problem? Is there a better way to deal with this situation?

Comment: There are libraries like Picasso?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel especially if you're new to Android. When you can, search for libraries that already handle the task for you. For image loading there are many, Picasso is a great choice. For other information using an HTTP API try Retrofit (made by the same people who created Picasso).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very popular kind of thing to do in each and every android app. Surely, you don't want to store any of the feed (for instance) pictures on your device manually and that's why there are so many useful libs for this kind of stuff.

Personally, I love to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). This lib is recommended by Google because of tons of advantages in comparison with, for instance Picasso. At least, it can work with Gifs and is more reliable to the device's hardware. There are some articles around, you should read more, if you want to know more.

About ListView. Don't use it. Just don't. There is a RecyclerView class for this. It is maintained and is very cool for horizontal and vertical layouts. Definitely must-have read for you now. And don't forget to read about ViewHolder pattern before going to code something, 'cause it helps to avoid extra memory and CPU usage (better work with recreating and refilling the views).

By the way, if you need a robust and fast solution, there are also many solutions of packed recyclerview libs that work "out of the box". With 'em you wouldn't have to work with footers and headers for infinite lists or so. For example, you could play with this git repo: [UltimateRecyclerView](https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateRecyclerView)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the library [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)! It's pretty simple, you just have to do this in your adapter of the listview:

`Glide.with(this).load("url of the image").into(imageView);`

And it will be smooth!